# Pandas read_csv from a stream

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Trying to load a dataframe from a stream using `requests.get(stream=True)` and `iter_lines` but its not working right.

Tried the sample solution as well from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18915941/create-a-pandas-dataframe-from-generator), but doesnt seem to be working for me.

Here is the sample solution to populate the dataframe using a generator of string (csv representation):

```
import pandas as pd

print(pd.__version__)

def gen():
    lines = [
        'col1,col2\n',
        'foo,bar\n',
        'foo,baz\n',
        'bar,baz\n'
    ]
    for line in lines:
        yield line

class Reader(object):
    def __init__(self, g):
        self.g = g
    def read(self, n=0):
        try:
            return next(self.g)
        except StopIteration:
            return ''

df = pd.read_csv(Reader(gen()))
```

My output is:

```
1.0.5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
    df = pd.read_csv(Reader(gen()))
  File "\.virtualenvs\TEST-gzvLffvD\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 676, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "\.virtualenvs\TEST-gzvLffvD\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 431, in _read
    filepath_or_buffer, encoding, compression
  File "\.virtualenvs\TEST-gzvLffvD\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 200, in get_filepath_or_buffer
    raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'Reader'>
```

If i just pass the generator as is:

```
df = pd.read_csv(gen())
```

I get the error:

```
ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'generator'>
```

How do I get this working? To basically stream data to dataframe from a generator of csv string representaion.

Comment: class needed an `__iter__` method

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the [`pd.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) constructor which excepts a tuple generator:

```
import pandas as pd

print(pd.__version__)

def gen():
    lines = [
        'col1,col2\n',
        'foo,bar\n',
        'foo,baz\n',
        'bar,baz\n'
    ]
    for line in lines:
        yield tuple(line.strip().split(","))

df = pd.DataFrame(gen())
```

```
      0     1
0  col1  col2
1   foo   bar
2   foo   baz
3   bar   baz
```

^ Not the exact output you want, so you'll have to modify the solution to get the right column labels.

Comment: Yea the document for pd.read_csv should be able to take an object that has 'read' method, not sure why its not working.  Did you get the same error with the sample code?